# How to define recursive foreign key on 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, relational-database

I'm writing a small app to manage metadata for menus. A `Menu` is attached to an `App`, and is also (optionally) attached to a another `Menu` (therefore defining a submenu). So the wiring goes like this: attach `Menu.AppId` to `App.Id`, and then `Menu.ParentId` to `Menu.Id` to define submenus.

**But this can let me insert incoherent data:**

```
INSERT INTO Menu (Id, ParentId, AppId, Desc) values (1, NULL, 25, 'Top Menu')
INSERT INTO Menu (Id, ParentId, AppId, Desc) values (2, 1, 36, 'Sub Menu')
```

Here I just stated that **Sub Menu** of App **#36** should be under **Top Menu** of App **#25** (another App).

Is there a way I can define a constraint to make sure that when I insert **Sub Menu** as a child of **Top Menu**, the App has to be #25 (triggers are not an option)?

(Of course I will manage this in the user interface, but I'm also looking for a way to secure the model).

Thank you,

Comment: Why are triggers not an option?

Comment: @HLGEM I'm looking for a built-in functionality provided by RDBMS that I could have missed. I'd like to learn about all possible options before using a trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a foreign key constraint

First constraint `(Id, AppId)` to be unique (it is obvious if `Id` is the PK but it is needed to check the following FK constraint):

```
alter table Menu add constraint unique_app unique (Id, AppId)
```

Then constraint a child to have the same `AppId` :

```
alter table Menu add constraint fk_same_parent_app
foreign key (ParentId, AppId) references Menu(Id, AppId)
```

Edit: If you need to change the AppId, it must be done at once for every menu in the hierarchy.
This can be done with a recursive query using a CTE :

```
with AMenu(Id, ParentId)
as (
  -- start with a root
  select Id, ParentId
  from Menu where Id = <id_of_a_root>
union all 
  -- recursively add children
  select m.Id, m.ParentId
  from Menu m 
  join Amenu am on m.ParentId = am.Id
)
update m
set AppId = <some_value>
from Menu m 
join AMenu am 
on m.Id = am.Id
```

Comment: This looks good but once I added children to a parent, I can no longer change its AppId (of course it's natural). Any suggestion to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have a way but it requires you to make appid allow nulls. In this case the appid would only be in the parent.

```
create table #temp (parentid int null,  appid int NUll)
ALTER TABLE #temp
ADD CONSTRAINT myconstraint CHECK (parentid+appid = Null and (isnull(parentid, 0)+isnull(appid,0) = parentid  or isnull(parentid, 0)+isnull(appid,0) = appid));

insert #temp
values(1,null)
insert #temp
values(null,1)
insert #temp
values(1,1)
```

I don't know it that kind of structure would work for you but it was the only way I could see to come up with a working check constraint.